# detect sequence of repeating elements

Tags: algorithm, sequence, repeat

I have an array of random numbers lets say:

[10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20, **11**, **12**, **14**,25,25,26,27,28,29]

I have to detect repeated sequences (witch are in fact errors)

with length bigger then a specific number (2).

Is there any good algorithm for this ?

what I have for now:

```
int minLenght = 3;
int[] data = {1,2,3};

for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
        if ( data[i] == data[j]){
            int l = 0;
            int ii = i;
            int jj = j;
            while(data[ii] == data[jj]){
                ii++;
                jj++;
                l++;
            }
            if(l >= minLenght){
                print('['+i+'-'+ii+'] same as ['+j+'-'+jj+']');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are restrictions on memory usage and execution time? what is expected length of a sequence?

Comment: no memory restrictions, the set is usually 20-200 items
and repeated sequences are rare (errors).The checked length is 5(but may change).

Answer (score 4):

One way is to store sequences of length L (one bigger than your specific length) in a hash table.

If you ever find a sequence is already in the hash table, then you have found a repeat of length >= L.

e.g. Python code

```
A=[10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,11,12,14,25,25,26,27,28,29]
S=set()
L=2+1
for i in xrange(len(A)-L+1):
    key=tuple(A[i:i+L])
    if key in S:
        print i
    else:
        S.add(key)
```

This prints out the locations of repeated sequences with length greater than 2.

Comment: thanks for the idea (I start to like python).
But L should "minimum length" and there is no reference to the first sequence.

Comment: You can modify this method slightly to get the index of the first sequence too. Change `S=set()` to `S=dict()`; change `S.add(key)` to `S[key] = i`; and change `print i` to `print S[key]`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a special algorithm for this, but my proposal would be this:

```
loop1 over array[i]:
  loop2 over array[j] starting with i+1:
    dist=array[j]-array[i];
    if dist==specific_number:
      array_result.append(array[i] +""+""+array[j])
```

This would be my simple logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regexps, except the list format shown is irregular. I use Python below and 'regularise' the list format turning it into a string before applying a regular expression looking for duplicated sequences of numbers/non-numbers:

```
>>> import re
>>> numbers = [10,11,12,14,15,16,17,18,19,20, 11, 12, 14,25,25,26,27,28,29]
>>> sep = ', '
>>> txt = sep + sep.join(str(x) for x in numbers) + sep
>>> txt
', 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 11, 12, 14, 25, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, '
>>> re.search(r'\D((?:\d+\D+){2,}).*\1', txt).groups()
('11, 12, 14, ',)
```

I normally try and minimize my use of regexps but this does detect the duplication.